# 'exported' csv data appears in my Firefox console log rather than an exported .csv file (Yii 1.x)

Tags: php, csv, yii, http-headers, export-to-csv

I have a form that once submitted pulls some data from my database that I attempted to have download immediately into a csv document.

For some reason the data is all fine, in the correct csv format however it only appears in the console log in my Firefox browser rather than a file that is automatically downloaded e.g exported.csv

I have the following functions - I get no errors as everything is working but for some reason it doesn't download the csv automatically.. I presume my issue is within my outputCsv function.

Any ideas?

```
public function actionSurveyStats()
{
    $id = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
    $model = SurveyQuestionnaires::model()->findByPK($id);

    $this->bodyTitle = 'Your Survey';

    if (isset($_POST[get_class($model)])) {
        set_time_limit(0);
        ini_set('memory_limit', '786M');
        $filename = 'questionnaire_' .time(). '.csv';
        $completed->questionnaire_id = Yii::app()->request->getPost('questionnaire_id');
        $organisation_id = $_POST[get_class($model)]['organisation_id'];
        $this->outputCsv($model->getExportData($organisation_id), $filename);
    }

    $this->render('survey_stats',array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}


protected function outputCsv($rows, $filename = '') {
    if (empty($filename)) {
        $filename = (!is_null($this->model)) ? (strtolower(get_class($this->model)."_".$this->model->getPrimaryKey().".csv")) : "export.csv";
    }

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Type: application/csv") ;
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Cache-control: private");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    echo stream_get_contents($fp);
    fclose($fp);

    app()->end();
}
```

Comment: I don't have knowledge of Yii framework but are you submitting form using Ajax?

Comment: Excellent!!! that was it..

Comment: Great. Good to know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix... was the ajax in the form.. set this to false & it works now! Thanks Yogesh

Simply needed to set 'enableAjaxValidation' to false.

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
'id'                    => get_class($model),
'type'                  => 'horizontal',
'enableAjaxValidation'  => false,
'clientOptions'         => array(
    'validateOnSubmit'      => true,
    'validateOnChange'      => false,
    'validateOnType'        => false,
),
'htmlOptions'       => array(
    'class'                 => '',
    'autocomplete'          => 'off',
    'enctype'               => 'multipart/form-data'
),
)); ?>
```